# How to access values from inside multidemensional arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

ok sorry ill re-write this as i tried to use a simplified example but I believe its more complicated so im trying to get all users who meet a certain criteria , then put them in an array, after that shuffle the order and put the users in array chunks.

From there im doing a if / else statement saying if each chunk is full do there IDs but im having trouble getting the IDs:

```
//Get all users who are eligable
$eligable_users = get_users('meta_key=eligable&meta_value=1');


//Set all eligable users into an array
$eligable_user_array = array();
foreach ( $eligable_users as $users ) {
$eligable_user_array[] = $users;
}

//Shuffle users among arrays 
shuffle($eligable_user_array); 


//Change this to adjust chunk size 
$winning_array_chunk_size = 2;

//Create array chunks
$array_chunk = array_chunk($eligable_user_array , $winning_array_chunk_size , false);


//Foreach array chunk
foreach($array_chunk as $individual_winner_chunk) {


//If a chunk isnt filled igonre
if( sizeof($individual_winner_chunk) < $winning_array_chunk_size) {
    //Users in this chunk arnt entered into prize draw
} 

//For each filled chunk get a user
else{
        //print_r($individual_winner_chunk);

        //Get randomised users from each chunk
        $random_user_from_chunk = array_rand($individual_winner_chunk , 1);
        foreach($random_user_from_chunk as $userchunk){
            echo $userchunk->data->ID;
        }


    }
```

THis is the part not outputting properly:

echo $userchunk->data->ID;

Comment: What is the output? Please add it to the question.

Comment: Output is jsut blank however if I uncomment the print_r at the bottom that output looks like :

rray
(
    [0] => WP_User Object
        (
            [data] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 7

Comment: The problem is how you use array_rand. Please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the array_rand function incorrectly.

array_rand returns the random key.
Check here for more info : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

So if you only need one key then do:

```
   $random_user_from_chunk = array_rand($individual_winner_chunk , 1);

   echo $individual_winner_chunk[$random_user_from_chunk]->data->ID;
```

If you need more randomised users, increase the number option in array_rand

```
$random_user_from_chunk = array_rand($individual_winner_chunk , 2);
echo $individual_winner_chunk[$random_user_from_chunk[0]]->data->ID
echo $individual_winner_chunk[$random_user_from_chunk[1]]->data->ID
```

Comment: Should be ->data->ID

Comment: Yep. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Please accept the answer if its the solution.

Answer (score -1):

If your `$userlist` values are fetched from JSON, then you can simply apply to change objects into associative arrays:

`$random_user = array_rand(json_decode($userlist, TRUE), 1);`

and then you can access as:

```
foreach($random_user as $individual_user) {
echo $individual_user['data']['ID'];
}
```